# Quokka returning variable data in a function even if it's not invoke

Tags: javascript, node.js

Quokka is returning my function value without invoking it is this a bug?

I compare it with google chrome console and it gives me the error that I'm expecting. [VM1146:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined]

```
// Quokka
const test = () => {
    return a = 1;
};

let b = a + a;

console.log(b); 2

// Chrome console
const test = () => {
    return a = 1;
};

let b = a + a;

console.log(b);
VM1146:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined
    at <anonymous>:5:9
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is a bug but my guess is that with Quokka, `a` is being hoisted

Comment: Yeah, I think it was. Thanks @Aaron